# How to find the patents an agent has drafted or prosecuted?

Tags: attorney, patent-agent

Left with no other choices, and convinced by the comments in here that using an agent is better than doing it by myself, I'm in the process of finding an experienced patent agent able to draft a good quality patent specification and prosecute it.

I'm currently checking agents websites, bios etc, but I am not sure how to find the patents they actually wrote and prosecuted.
I tried google patent, but it seems I can only punch in the names in the authors field, and like that I'm getting very little results on the names I'm checking.
So I wonder if what google tells is all the data I can find or if there are other ways to search for these info and evaluate agents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used this feature, but you can search on [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) for "Agents & Attorneys". The Lens is free to use and you don't need to register. If you do register you get some additional useful features, but it is still free.

Personally, I would focus an an agent or attorney with experience with the field of your invention. One way to find these is to search for relevant prior art and see who the agent or attorney is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my case i see that most of related patents are submitted by major vendors, so i assume they use either internal agents or large law firms, but it's worth a shot!

Comment: @Pa_ Good luck!  You’re smart to evaluate the agent’s work.